# extracting python dictionary key,value pairs into strings or iterables 'key1,key2,...' and [value1,value2,...]

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, dictionary, string-formatting

using psycopg2 and postgresql 9.3 requires a row to be inserted into a table using the following syntax:

```
cur.execute(
'INSERT INTO customer (name,address) VALUES ('Herman M', '1313 mockingbird lane'))
```

If the data comes in a dictionary {'name':'Herman M','address':'1313 mockingbird lane'} is there a better, more pythonic way to extract the keys and values from the dictionary in order than this:

```
    fields,values = '',[]
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        fields = ','.join((fields,k))
        values.append((v))
```

In order to do this:

```
    cur.execute(
    "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES {}".format(
        tablename,fields[1:],tuple(values)))
```

It works, but after watching Raymond Hettinger give his talk on transforming code into beautiful idiomatic python I am sensitive to the fact that it is ugly and I am copying data. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Use the dictionary in the `cursor.execute` method

```
insert_query = """
    insert into customer (name, address)
    values (%(name)s, %(address)s)
"""
insert_dict = {
    'name': 'Herman M',
    'address': '1313 mockingbird lane'
}

cursor.execute(insert_query, insert_dict)
```